# Is there any way to get the first 5 characters of a GUID?

Tags: c#

From what I understand the following code will create a string looking like "xxxx-xxxxx .. etc"

```
UserUId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

What I would like to do is to capture the first five x's. I know I can do this to get the first 4 but how can I skip the "-" and get the first 5, without first putting the Guid into a variable and then using that variable twice with substrings.

```
UserUId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4);
```

Comment: I feel like I should leave this here: [GUIDs are globally unique, but substrings of GUIDs aren't](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080627-00/?p=21823)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `N` format specifier to get the guid without any extra formatting:

```
UserUId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 5);
```

Comment: @Alan2 - Yes.Sorry, I forgot to change the 4 to a 5

Answer (score 1):

If you want to split the text into sub-strings like abc-def-ghi you can use [`String.Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Split_System_Char___):

```
string text="abc-def-ghi";
string[] array=  text.Split('-'); //character
```

Now array[0] will contain "abc", array[1] will contain "def", and array[2] will contain "ghi".

Comment: OP doesn't want to split the string, OP wants to get the first 5 characters `xxxx-x` of the GUID string without having to create multiple substrings and then recombine them.